# how to save a string value to a datatable item that has int type

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have a datatable with a column that is named `Month`.
Month column has `int` type by default(I have stored a month to datatable from a sql server table).
I want to set `datatable.Rows[0]["Month"]` to a string like: "hello".
how can I do this?

Comment: You can't. That makes no sense whatsoever. What possible use could this be to you? Why not just make the column a `string` and convert between `string`s and `int`s?

Comment: better use `nvarchar` or `varchar` :)

Comment: My table in database saves month as `int` and as I said, I save this table in `datatable`. I need to have name of months as string to create a monthly archive.

Comment: in answer to  Steve: Is there any way to convert column type to string or no?

Comment: @aliso That still doesn't make sense, just use a numeric representation for each month. 1 for Jan, 2 for Feb, you get the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `Month` column to `string` instead of `int` .
Here is example ,

```
  DataTable _dt= new DataTable();
        _dt.Columns.Add("Month", typeof(string));
```